# facebook api login issue

Tags: php, facebook, authentication, facebook-php-sdk

Im trying to retrieve data from
    http://www.facebook.com/ajax/shares/view/?target_fbid=410558838979218&__a=1
I get mix of js and html with sharing information if I open this link through my browser, but if I use

```
$url = 'http://www.facebook.com/ajax/shares/view/?target_fbid=410558838979218&__a=1';
$html = file_get_contents($url);
```

I get

> "Not Logged In","errorDescription":"Please log in to continue.","payload":{"_*dialog":{"title":{"*_html":"Not Logged In"},"body":{"__html":"Please log in to continue.................

and etc
I understand that i need to be logged in, i tried login through facebook api:

```
$config = array(
'appId' => '**********',
'secret' => '**********',
);
$facebook = new Facebook($config);
$user_id = $facebook->getUser();
```

Im gettin user and etc, everything's okay, but retreiving share information fails anyways
How can I "properly" login to solve this issue?
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're using the SDK initialisation code but trying to scrape facebook.com's web interface - these are not compatible things

You'd need to automate the login to facebook.com via your code as well and handle all the cookies if you want to scrape, buy doing so is explicitly against Facebook's TOS and could get you in legal trouble if you persist